# How to use latex without install any package to type some physical notation?

Tags: packages, delimiters

Recently, I am a physics master student and I find the Typora is a good app to take notes from lecture, writing critique and summarize and organize ideas. However, I find that Typora does not support to install other packages such like bracket and other. In order to solve this problem, I use  `\left \langle \middle| {A \over B} \middle| \right\rangle` to fix it.

Of course it is not a perfect solution. Is any good idea for similar situation?

Answer (score 1):

Notes in inline math?

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[xetex,12pt,a4paper]{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$ some notes about some stuff.\\

$\left \langle \middle| {A \over B} \middle| \right\rangle$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

[typora issues-#100](https://github.com/typora/typora-issues/issues/100)
latex package: physics

I won't configure that either.

Another way:

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.6-latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros
Enter custom commands in math mode :

```
$$
\newcommand\mycmd{\left \langle \middle| {A \over B} \middle| \right\rangle}
$$
```

And then restart typora. Ok. The commands defined by this method are only valid for this file.